# Override bad/wrong values in a main table with NA or null values listed on another lookup table in R

Tags: r, replace, overriding, lookup, assign

The main table is large.

Has certain undesired values that I want to override.

I am writing into a lookup table the keys and new_value (NA) to override.

Both have 2 keys (session_id and datetime), not one unique.

- Other similar questions goes into replacing an NA with a value, but I want to replace the value with an NA. Clear cells contents.
- The 2 keys limits the use of match() which can handle only one key and first occurrences.
- left_join or merge operations, would create a new large dataframe with an added column, and will fill them up with NA for every row, and it would also require to perform some 'coalescing' into an NA value, which I guess, doesn't exists.

I don't want to remove the entire row, as there are many other columns with its own values. I just want to delete that value from that cells.

I think, that in short, it is just an assignment operation to a filtered subset based on 2 keys. Something like:
`table[ lookup_paired_keys(session_ids, lookup_datetimes) ] <- NA`

Follows a sample dataset with undesired "0" to replace by NA. The real dataset may contain other kind of values.

```
table <- read.table(text = "
 session_id  datetime CaloriesDaily
 1233815059 2016-05-01 5555
 8583815123 2016-05-03 4444
 8512315059 2016-05-04 2432
 8583815059 2016-05-12    0
 6290855005 2016-05-10    0
 8253242879 2016-04-30    0
 1503960366 2016-05-20    0
 1583815059 2016-05-19 2343
 8586545059 2016-05-20 1111
 1290855005 2016-05-11 5425
 1253242879 2016-04-25 1234
 1111111111 2016-05-09 6542", header = TRUE)
table$datetime     = as.POSIXct(table$datetime, tz='UTC')
table

lookup <- read.table(text = "
 session_id  datetime CaloriesDaily
 8583815059 2016-05-12   NA
 6290855005 2016-05-10   NA
 8253242879 2016-04-30   NA
 1503960366 2016-05-12   NA", header = TRUE)
lookup$datetime     = as.POSIXct(lookup$datetime, tz='UTC')
lookup$CaloriesDaily = as.numeric(lookup$CaloriesDaily)
lookup
```

## SOLVED

After reading the accepted answer, I want to share the final outcome.
And as I have the main table a data.table and I got some warns regarding nomenclature, be aware that I am no expert, but is working with this example dataset and my own.

##### lookup_by : Standard Lookup operation

```
lookup_by <- function(table, lookup, by) {
  merge( table, lookup, by=by )
}


### usage ###
keys = c('session_id','datetime')
lookup_by( table, lookup, keys)
```

### Adopted solution: match_by

Like match() but with keys.
It returns a vectors with row numbers when keys match.
So that, assignment like `table[ ..matches.. ] <- NA` is possible.

```
match_by <- function(table, lookup, by) {
  table <- setDT(table)[,..by]
  table$idx1 <- 1:nrow(table) 
  lookup <- setDT(lookup)[,..by]
  lookup$idx2 <- 1:nrow(lookup)
  m <- merge( table ,  lookup,   by=by )
  return( m[ ,c('idx1','idx2') ] )
}

### usage ###
keys = c('session_id','datetime')
rows = match_by( table, lookup, keys)
overrides <- c(lookup[ rows$idx2, 'CaloriesDaily' ])
table[ rows$idx1, 'CaloriesDaily' ] <- overrides
table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a solution using `dplyr::semi_join()` and `dplyr::anti_join()` to split your dataframe based on whether the id and date keys match your lookup table. I then assign `NA`s in just the subset with matching keys, then row-bind the subsets back together. Note that this solution doesn’t preserve the original row order.

```
library(dplyr)

table_ok_vals <- table %>%
  anti_join(lookup, by = c("session_id", "datetime"))

table_replaced_vals <- table %>%
  semi_join(lookup, by = c("session_id", "datetime")) %>%
  mutate(CaloriesDaily = NA_real_)
  
table <- bind_rows(table_ok_vals, table_replaced_vals)

table
```

Output:

```
   session_id   datetime CaloriesDaily
1  1233815059 2016-05-01          5555
2  8583815123 2016-05-03          4444
3  8512315059 2016-05-04          2432
4  1503960366 2016-05-20             0
5  1583815059 2016-05-19          2343
6  8586545059 2016-05-20          1111
7  1290855005 2016-05-11          5425
8  1253242879 2016-04-25          1234
9  1111111111 2016-05-09          6542
10 8583815059 2016-05-12            NA
11 6290855005 2016-05-10            NA
12 8253242879 2016-04-30            NA
```